# what is the way of dealing with textual valued feature vectors for classification task?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, natural-language

I aim to work on twitter data for sentiment analysis but I am curios for the way of dealing such a huge number of textual features (words). Is using the Bag-Of-Words approach is the best? However I've learnt that using all the words on tweets is better approach so how the state of art methods dealing with such a textual classification problem?